# Headless Eevee rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Going off of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/blender-2-8-aws-ec2-command-line-eevee-render/150532#150532) answer I am looking to run an Eevee render on an external server. How can I do this using [VirtualGL](https://virtualgl.org/)? And what are the hardware requirements of this?

Answer (score 2):

This may work (not quite knowing the context):

```
!apt-get install python-opengl -y

!apt install xvfb -y

!pip install pyvirtualdisplay

!pip install piglet


from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
Display().start()
```

---

And you may not need piglet and xvfb, I have yet to test.

Source:
Answer by Shrawan Agrawal
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107530/how-to-render-openai-gym-in-google-colab