# Is there no way of rendering headless using EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, command-line

I am using a computer without good graphics card and a remote LINUX server with a K40 Tesla card. I am operating on a remote server by MobaX to get the rendering working. For now I'm using Cycles to render and everything works just fine, here is my command:

```
blender -b -noaudio /Path/to/File/NAME.blend -P /Path/to/scripts/linux_enable_GPU.py -P /Path/to/demo/run.py -o //results/part{variable}.mp4 -a -- variable
```

The `linux_enable_GPU.py` helps me to enable the GPU as well as setting the engine to *Cycles* and *Cuda* and the `run.py` helps me to create actions.

---

However, sometimes it is quite expensive to render a simple scene using *Cycles* so I'd like to use *Eevee* to render my animations.

I tried lot to make it work. According to the official guide, I use:

```
blender -b  -noaudio test_eevee.blend -E BLENDER_EEVEE -a
```

to call for *Eevee* engine but it failed. In debug mode I get:

> Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
> /run/user/1205/gvfs/ non-existent directory
> Read blend: /home/blender/works/demo/test_eevee.blend
> read file /home/blender/works/demo/test_eevee.blend
> Version 292 sub 15 date 2021-02-24 16:25 hash 02948a2cab44
> Writing: /tmp/test_eevee.crash.txt
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And in *debug-all* mode I get a lot of errors:

[image: it seems to be caused by the errors in the picture]

Seems that *Eevee* does not support headless rendering: [Headless Eevee rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/153620/) However, it seems that we can fake a display to use *Eevee*. But the script in that Q&A is not crystal clear and I'm using Blender 2.92 version.

Is there any way to render headless using EEVEE?

Comment: AFAICT rendering should work if you have a graphics card installed. Have you tried setting the render engine in your blend file? ... and then run the usual `blender -b file.blend -a`? Seems you GL configs are messed up. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/blender-2-8-aws-ec2-command-line-eevee-render Also I recommend take the tour to learn how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: How can I fake a display?   The method in the first link is not very clear

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: Yes I have set the engine as EEVEE before, and I also learned that eevee does not support headless render. I think that maybe there is something wrong with my gl but I dont know much about it

Comment: ... and you get the same error? Again, if you have a graphics card installed it should work fine, rendering headless does not work *without* a graphics card installed however, or any hacks to fake a display driver (seems not needed in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Check my self answered question here:

[How do you use Eevee renderer in a Docker container using bpy?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/232961/how-do-you-use-eevee-renderer-in-a-docker-container-using-bpy)

It's instructions for how to use Eevee in a container, but the instructions are directly translatable to your scenario.

Basically what you would do is create a service that starts `xvfb`.

Fair warning though, in my experience Eevee doesn't have nearly as impressive a speedup when run in this manner. Not sure if it's because `xvfb` doesn't offer the best performance, but after I tested for a while I decided to simply stick to Cycles when running in a headless environment. Eevee was faster, but an image that took maybe 5 seconds to render when running Eevee on my actual computer took like 10 times longer running as a container, whereas Cycles was maybe 3 times longer.

So, for me at least, my result was that:

Eevee = 5 seconds per frame * 10 times slowdown = 50 seconds per frame using xvfb

Cycles = 30 seconds per frame * 3 times slowdown = 1 minute 30 seconds per frame, doesn't require xvfb

So again, for me Eevee was still faster, and rendering roughly 30% faster is still nice, but I so vastly prefer the results from Cycles that it didn't feel worth the added hassle just to get a worse result faster. When Eevee was vastly superior in performance I could live with a less appealing result, but headless Eevee led me to prefer the idea of running multiple Cycles renders simultaneously on multiple servers then merging the results.