# "Unable to open a display" AWS EC2 Background Rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, command-line

I launched an AWS EC2 T3 Medium Ubuntu 20.04 instance and installed blender 2.83.9
When I launch the simple command line `blender -b -f 1` I get this error message :

```
Blender 2.83.9 (hash 5be9ef417703 built 2021-01-19 16:16:34)

ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default /run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory found
bundled python: /home/ubuntu/blender-2.91.2-linux64/2.91/python Unable to open a display

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I searched on the web and it has to do with EEVEE and OpenGL needing a display. I was wondering if there was any solution to this problem. I found a few but it uses GPU rendering on AWS P Instances. I would like to render on General Purpose Instances.

Thanks.

Comment: [Blender 2.8 - AWS EC2 command line EEVEE render - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/blender-2-8-aws-ec2-command-line-eevee-render), [Blender 2.8: "Unable to open a display" by the rendering on the background (Eevee) - Blender Development - Blender Developer Talk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-unable-to-open-a-display-by-the-rendering-on-the-background-eevee/1436)

Comment: I got the same issue and realized that I was using Eevee instead of cycles in `.blend` file it worked after I changed it to cycles. Apparently Eevee doesn't support headless rendering https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150532/121173