# Rendering worked one time and now is not working

Tags: python, rendering

I am trying to make PHP and Blender Python render a 3d model to a website in headless mode. My server is an Ubuntu Linux server on a DigitalOcean droplet.

This worked one time and successfully gave an output of the render. I deleted the png render to try again and it does not work anymore.
Using Blender 3.0.1 for the blend file it is trying to read and `blender -v` on Linux reads the same version.

Code:

```php
<?php
$head = '
import bpy
import os
bpy.app.debug = True
';
$save = '
# Set the environment variable to indicate running in background mode
os.environ["BLENDER_OPTS"] = "--background"

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="/var/www/projects/game/render/umi2.blend")

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type == "MESH":
        ob.select_set(True)
    else:
        ob.select_set(False)

bpy.ops.object.join()

bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected()

origAlphaMode = bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/var/www/projects/game/cdn/renders/avatars/53.png"
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Reset the alpha mode to its original value
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = origAlphaMode

';
$python = "
$head
$save
";
echo "$python";
//echo "successfully rendered";
        $pyFileName = "/var/www/projects/game/render/render.py";
    file_put_contents($pyFileName, $python);
    //exec(escapeshellcmd("blender --background --python /var/www/projects/game/render/render.py"));
    $blenderCommand = "blender --background --python /var/www/projects/game/render/render.py 2>&1";
        putenv("DISPLAY=:0");

        $output = shell_exec($blenderCommand);
        echo"<h5>Output</h5><code>";
        echo $output."</code>";
?>
```

Log: (When going to url to render it in background)

```py
import bpy import os bpy.app.debug = True # Set the environment variable to indicate running in background mode os.environ["BLENDER_OPTS"] = "--background" bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="/var/www/projects/game/render/umi2.blend") for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects: if ob.type == "MESH": ob.select_set(True) else: ob.select_set(False) bpy.ops.object.join() bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view_selected() origAlphaMode = bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = True bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/var/www/projects/game/cdn/renders/avatars/53.png" bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) # Reset the alpha mode to its original value bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = origAlphaMode
Output
Color management: using fallback mode for management Color management: Error could not find role data role. Blender 3.0.1 Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard". Read blend: /var/www/projects/game/render/umi2.blend Unable to open a display Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help would be appreciated, again it did work one time so I'm not sure why it's not anymore CHMOD is set to 7777 practically everywhere.

Comment: I've edited your tags. It is helpful if you are talking about python to have the python tag on the question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294098/why-does-my-cube-not-render-in-python Seems related. EEVEE cannot just render without display connected to GPU. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/blender-2-8-aws-ec2-command-line-eevee-render/174537#174537

Comment: What is up with the outdated 3.0.1 version everywhere? Just use Snap Store or [download current version from the website](https://www.blender.org/download/).