# Why does my cube not render in python

Tags: python, 3d-view, error

```
import bpy
bpy.app.debug = True
# Set the environment variable to indicate running in background mode
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="/var/www/projects/render/cube.blend")
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/var/www/projects/cdn/temps/cube.png"
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Reset the alpha mode to its original value
bpy.context.scene.render.film_transparent = origAlphaMode
```

the bpy.ops.render.render(write still=True) line
No addons are used its vanilla blender 3.0.1 and the Blender on my linux server is also 3.0.1 why is the most basic thing not running?

I am using a digital ocean droplet. Also I have used renderings on 2.79 for a long time with no issues.

Debug:
Blender 3.0.1
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
/run/user/0/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read blend: /var/www/projects/render/cube.blend
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
Unable to open a display
Aborted (core dumped)

I really dont mind the other errors just the core dump is my priority.

Comment: Color management resetting from Filmic to "Standard" will mess the colors up a lot. How are you running the script? You should not run any code after bpy.ops.render.render(). Render is multi-threaded and may happen on multiple devices, python script does not 'know' when rendering is done and if you have code that tries to run after render is started you may get unexpected results. It would be better if you provided some more context. What you are trying to do here? Also why use such an outdated version?

Comment: How is this related to Linux server? Please provide full context.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Hey I dont even use filmic blender is being dumb and its relating to linux servers because Im running the python on it also idk if its colors it might be but I literally run bpy and it crashes every time it worked one time but now it doesnt work I dont use filmic I use standard but it forces filmic for some reason even if blender has it to standard and even if i change to filmic it says filmic is missing or something it makes no sense

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Also its a grey cube even a basic render I changed it to standard im not getting color errors literally just goes unable to open display core dumped

Comment: Blender uses Filmic for years now. Is the file saved in 2.79? Make sure it works on your PC first. If you are trying to render with EEVEE, it might need a monitor connected to GPU for OpenGL rendering. Update to current version, it might be improved now. Also if you render on a server, I have no idea how you are trying to do that now, but you should probably try [rendering from command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html) You can specify Python script to run if you need to modify something in the file form command line render.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys no its the current blender for the cube

Comment: OK. Makes sense. Current version file will not work with 3.0.1.

Comment: Im trying to do a headless render on my server so it cant monitor also I already do that.. its bpy blender python which runs blender --background --python /link/to/py.py and the codes says the import bpy and all the codes to get it to run should I just change it to cycles lol

Comment: No.. the cube is using 3.0.1 sorry for confusion, I made sure that it matched up I meant latest package for linux

Comment: oh I think eevee doesnt work on bpy natively

Comment: Use `snap install blender` to update Blender to current version on your Linux server. Then make sure you use [CLI rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html) correctly. If you render from command line, you don't need to run render operator in a script. Might that be the problem?

Comment: [It](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/54638) doesn't seem to be fixed yet. There seems to be [a workaround worth checking out.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174537/60759)