# How to determine whether blender background rendering has ended？

Tags: python, rendering

For example, I want to automatically shut down my computer after the background rendering is completed, the command I used is

`start blender -b "path to the project file" -E BLENDER_EEVEE -o//"exported path" -a`

I need to add `start` at the front, otherwise Blender will enter a pseudo death state after execution. However, with `start` added, the system will open an additional backend process for Blender to perform rendering operations.

But I don't know how to listen to this process, and when I try to use the subprocess module in Blender Python, it reports an error, The last line in the traceback says:

`FileNotFoundError: [winError 2] The system cannot find the specified file`

Does anyone know how to solve this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code which produces the `FileNotFoundError`?

Answer (score 1):

A couple other things that look fishy in your example command:

- `-o//"exported path"` the whole path should be inside the quotation marks: `-o "//exported path"`
- `start` shouldn't be necessary, its only purpose is to run a process so that you keep the control of the console instead of waiting for the process to finish. But if you use Blender's CLI correctly, it should return control when done processing AFAIK.

Other than that, I'm a bit confused because, officially:

> There is currently no support for using Eevee on headless systems (i.e. without a Display Manager).
>
> **Sourbe: [Limitations — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html#headless-rendering)**

This means, unless you fake a display (like shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174537/53447)), you can't render in command line with Eevee. So you should use `CYCLES` instead.

And, practically, I haven't seen anyone render using Eevee or Workbench otherwise. But I just did some tests and it... Works?

But I'm using Windows 11's "Terminal" application, and with some addons (clink, wsl2 for GUI Linux, ...), so maybe that's why.